# combining two pairing id

Tags: r

```
df <- tibble(id=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
             x = c( NA, 1,NA, 1, 2,NA, 2,3,3,NA), 
             y = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,NA,NA,4))
```

If we have two pair ids (x and y), how can I create overall pair ids(y) which have common pairs (z)? Can we use `nest()`?

The dataset I would like to get is like this:

```
df <- tibble(id=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
             x = c( NA, 1,NA, 1, 2,NA, 2,3,3,NA),
             y = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,NA,NA,4), 
             z=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,2))
```

Comment: I don't think this is clear. In your first four rows, you have `z=1` but all `x,y` pairs are unique; whereas `z=3` both `x,y` are the same.

Comment: Yes, because within z=1, x and y keep paring (row 2 and row 4).

Comment: It still doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Hi, I simplified the data.

Comment: The sample data isn't the problem (as far as I can tell). The logic of how to determine `z` from `x` and `y` is unclear.

Comment: x is a pairing variable 1 and y is a paring variable 2. z is sharing pair ids.
For example, id2 and id4 are pairs in x and id1 and id2 are pairs in y and id 3 and id4 are pairs in y, so I would like to create the same id with id1-id4.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is achievable using some clustering methods from the *igraph* package:

```
library(igraph)
vars <- c("x","y")
# make an edge-list of all the relationships between `id` and `x`, and `id` and `y`
el <- cbind(id=df$id, edge=unlist(Map(paste, df[vars], vars, sep=".")))
# drop out any `NA` values that will cause over-grouping
el <- el[!grepl("^NA", el[,"edge"]),]
# create a graph and extract clusters
cl <- clusters(graph.edgelist(el))$membership

# get cluster labels to finalise
df$znew <- cl[match(df$id, names(cl))]
df
## A tibble: 10 x 5
#      id     x     y     z  znew
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  1.00 NA     1.00  1.00  1.00
# 2  2.00  1.00  1.00  1.00  1.00
# 3  3.00 NA     2.00  1.00  1.00
# 4  4.00  1.00  2.00  1.00  1.00
# 5  5.00  2.00  3.00  2.00  2.00
# 6  6.00 NA     3.00  2.00  2.00
# 7  7.00  2.00  4.00  2.00  2.00
# 8  8.00  3.00 NA     3.00  3.00
# 9  9.00  3.00 NA     3.00  3.00
#10 10.0  NA     4.00  2.00  2.00
```